# Cannot achieve this date format

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to name my uploaded image based on the date & time it is being uploaded.
So i used the following code to store the image name:

```
$imageName = date('d-m-y -H-i-s').'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

And it works pretty fine and my image name is like "6-6-2018 -14-14-14". But i want to achieve something like this "6-6-2018 14:14:14 ".
So i used the below code but it shows error.

```
$imageName = date('d-m-y H:i:s').'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

The error is :

**Could not move the file "C:\xampp\tmp\php1CBE.tmp" to "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public/storage/images\16-08-18 18:39:08.jpg" (move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php1CBE.tmp' to 'C:\xampp\htdocs\test\public/storage/images\16-08-18 18:39:08.jpg')**

How to solve this? Please help me .

Comment: Did the code work with the first code snippet you provided? Because this looks like a permissions issue.

Comment: On Windows the colon is not a valid character in a file name.

Comment: Yes   date('d-m-y -H-i-s')  works

Comment: So what to do ?

Comment: use the first code which works.

Comment: You will have to leave it like this. Because windows will not allow you to have *colon* in your filename.

Comment: But i wanted to achieve the second ! Is there any other way?

Comment: You have been told twice that your operating system does not allow colons in filenames. So no, there is no other way to get a colon in your filename. Use something else instead such as "_".

Comment: $imageName = date('d-m-Y .H.i.s').'.'.$request->pres_image->getClientOriginalExtension();                         i used this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** use a colon in a filename but here's a nice alternative

```
$imageName = date('YmdHis').'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

**For example the filename is:**

```
20180816170102.jpg
```

Where you display the image, you can **convert this string to any date format**

```
echo date("d-m-y H:i:s", strtotime(substr($filename, 0, 14));

16-08-18 17:01:01
```

Another plus is that the files are now also **sorted** correctly in your filesystem.

```
20180816170102.jpg
20180813133156.jpg
20180718190809.jpg
```